# What is ttstyledlayout

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20

Can someone explain how TTStyledLayout can be used?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a better understanding of [TTStyle](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/web/understanding-ttstyle).

Then check out [TTStyledLayout Class Reference](http://www.viz.co.kr/320api/interface_t_t_styled_layout.html)

Comment: A small typo, I wanted to know about TTStyledLayout

Comment: I needed somewhat like a tutorial.

Comment: yeah what is TTStyledLayout used for in a practical sense?